# add or delete value in listview

Tags: vb.net, listview, listviewitem

I want to delete only one item in `ListView`, here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 9 Step 1
    ListView1.Items.Add("Item111" & (i + 2))
    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add("Sub Item 1")
    'remove value
    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text = ""
    'add value, error return
    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text = "200"
Next
```

If I delete value text `Sub item 1` it can delete, however, when add some value like `200` I get error. Why?

Comment: Why don't you add the code that is not working?

Comment: ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text = "200" this line code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems pretty clear that you try to use an index to a subitems that doesn't exist. In Net the Index of any array start at index 0 not at index 1. You add just one subitem to your ListViewItem so if you want to change it you need to use the index 0 not the index 1

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 9 Step 1
    ListView1.Items.Add("Item111" & (i + 2))
    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add("Sub Item 1")
    ' No need to set the subitem to blank and the set it to 200
    ' change the subitem directly to the new value
    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(0).Text = "200"
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If this line is giving you an error, it might be because you're trying to assign an integer to a text property, try changing

```
ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text = 200
```

to

```
ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text = "200"
```

Comment: yes already i test with string value also is not working..sorry typoerror